# how to pass mysql query row value to php function

Tags: php, mysql

in my php script I have this mysql query:

```
$sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW search_best_rates_view AS SELECT *, 
         ".$this->get_rates(187,'2012-12-14','2012-12-18')."
          as my_best_rate FROM search_result_view 
       ";

mysql_query ( $sql );
```

which works fine (1,5s query time).

The Question: is there a way to replace any of the constants in the php function

```
.$this->get_rates($i,$a,$d)
```

e.g. in this example: '187' with a mysql row value

```
 search_result_view.my_ID
```

Comment: Have you tried that? What do you mean? Explosion Pills ?

Comment: if you ask if I've tried above: yes, that's why 1 got the 1,5s query response, all records were updated, unfortunately always with the same value, as I'm sending them as constants

Comment: Can you describe as precisely as possible what you want to appear in each row of your view?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Data Definition Language (DDL) statements such as `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` cannot contain any bound variables when they are passed to the MySQL server to be run.

So, you can do anything you want in PHP (or any other client language) to create DDL statements.  You can fetch values from MySQL tables if you like.  But by the time you issue the DDL statement as a query, it has to be a clean text string.

It looks like you're trying to put together DDL something like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW search_best_rates_view AS 
           SELECT *, 
                  123.45 as my_best_rate 
             FROM search_result_view
```

That will work.  So will something like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW search_best_rates_view AS 
           SELECT *, 
                  (SELECT MIN(rate) FROM rates) as my_best_rate 
             FROM search_result_view
```

But, it's not completely clear from your question what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Ollie, thanks for coming back to me. 
My php function $this->get_rates calculates (using mysql queries and some math) the 'best_rate'. 

I want to create+update a new table or create/replace a new view based on my existing table 'search_result_view ' where I insert in each row the result of my function. but to make the function work I'd need e.g. an id from that table